# Determin what worksheet to copy from another workbook based on data in a cell on the current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code to open and copy data from one workbook into another workbook. This code is something from another file that we use that was done by someone that no longer works with us.

I need to add to the code so that the Tab name it pulls data from on the file to be opened is in the current workbook on sheet 1 in cell Y2. The workbook I am pulling from has 14 tabs labled 1-14, the number I type in Y2 should determin the name of the tab from which data is to be copied. The code with the (????????????) is where I need the help.

I hope this makes sense, its much hardered to explain this then I thought.

THANKS!

---

```
Option Explicit

' ************************************************
' Variables For File Open Dialogue Box
' ************************************************
Public strDialogueFileTitle As String
Public strFilt As String
Public intFilterIndex As Integer
Public strCancel As String
Public strWorkbookNameAndPath As String
Public strWorkbookName As String
Public strWorksheetName As String

Public Sub Copy_TY()
Dim wkbVarianceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksVarianceWorksheett As Worksheet
Dim wkbImportedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksImportedWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngImportCopyRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wkbVarianceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set wksVarianceWorksheett = Sheets("TY")

' ****************************************************************************
' Prompt In The Dialogue Box
' ****************************************************************************
intFilterIndex = 1
strDialogueFileTitle = "Select The Workbook You Want To Import"

' ****************************************************************************
' Present the Open File Dialogue To The User
' ****************************************************************************
Call OpenFileDialogue

' ****************************************************************************
' Notify The User If No File Was Successfully Opened
' ****************************************************************************
If strCancel = "Y" Then
    MsgBox ("An Open Error Occurred Importing Your File Selection")
    Exit Sub
End If

' ****************************************************************************
' Set Imported Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' ****************************************************************************
Set wkbImportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets("?????????")

' ****************************************************************************
' Copy The Data (Paste Special Will Be The Next Example)
' ****************************************************************************
Set rngImportCopyRange = Range(wksImportedWorksheet.Cells(2, 1), Cells(250, 1)).EntireRow
rngImportCopyRange.Copy wksVarianceWorksheett.Cells(2, 1)

wkbVarianceWorkbook.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkbImportedWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wksVarianceWorksheett.Activate
wksVarianceWorksheett.Cells(1, 1).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Variance").Select

End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialogue()

' ************************************************
' Display a File Open Dialogue Box For The User
' ************************************************
strCancel = "N"
strWorkbookNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:=strFilt, _
     FilterIndex:=intFilterIndex, _
     Title:=strDialogueFileTitle)

' ************************************************
' Exit If No File Selected
' ************************************************
If strWorkbookNameAndPath = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No Filename Selected")
    strCancel = "Y"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf strWorkbookNameAndPath = "False" Then
    MsgBox ("You Clicked The Cancel Button")
    strCancel = "Y"
    Exit Sub
End If

' ******************************************************
' Now That You Have The User Selected File Name, Open It
' ******************************************************
Workbooks.Open strWorkbookNameAndPath
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, replace this line:

```
Set wkbImportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets("?????????")
```

by this line:

```
Dim wsName as String

wsName = wksVarianceWorksheet.Range("Y2").Value 'I only assumed you get Y2 value from this sheet which was declared in above. you can change and make another variable if your not pulling data from sheets TY
Set wkbImportedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksImportedWorksheet = wkbImportedWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
```

Hope this is what you need.